# Attack against $\operatorname{DESA}_{k,k_1} (x) \underset{\text{def}}= \operatorname{DES}_k(x)⊕k_1$

Tags: block-cipher, des, attack

Problem 5.16 in [this pdf](http://wiki.crypto.rub.de/Buch/en/download/problems_only/problems_chaptr_5.pdf), from the book: Christof Paar, Jan Pelzl, [Understanding Cryptography](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/%7Embarbulescu/cripto/Understanding%20Cryptography%20by%20Christof%20Paar%20.pdf)

> 5.16. This is your chance to break a cryptosystem. As we know by now, cryptography is a tricky business. The following problem illustrates how easy it is to turn a strong scheme into a weak one with minor modifications. We saw in this chapter that key whitening is a good technique for strengthening block ciphers against brute-force attacks. We now look at the following variant of key whitening against DES, which we’ll call DESA:
> $$\operatorname{DESA}_{k,k_1} (x) \underset{\text{def}}= \operatorname{DES}_k(x)⊕k_1$$
> Even though the method looks similar to key whitening, it hardly adds to the security. Your task is to show that breaking the scheme is roughly as difficult as a
> brute-force attack against single DES. Assume you have a few pairs of plaintext–
> ciphertext.

Comment: Looks like a ciphertext from DES XOR with a key k1, doesn't increase the security of a cipher at all. Anyone can explain it why ?

Comment: i don't understand the question very well.

Comment: The equation given defines a variant of DES, with two key components. You are given a few plaintext/ciphertext pairs $(p_i,c_i)$ with $c_i=\operatorname{DESA}_{k,k_1} (p_i)$. The goal is to find $k,k_1$.  You have a calculator/computer that can compute  $⊕$, and also $\operatorname{DES}_k(x)$ if given $k$ and $x$. Hint: How would you confirm/infirm a guess of $k$, with no clue given on $k_1$?

Comment: Hint: It is critical to note here that you have more than one plaintext-ciphertext pair.

Comment: Actually, it was solved with the hints. Apply brute force and for every key encrypt the two plaintexts and x-or the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normal DES**

Let's say you have a normal DES plaintext-ciphertext pair encrypted with 56 bits key $k$ where $C_1=DES_k(P_1)$.
In the worst case, one needs to try the $2^{56}$ possible keys to find the encryption key. And later on, one can decrypt all Ciphertext encrypted with the key $k$

**DESA**

Let's say one has 2 pairs of plaintext-ciphertext pairs ecnrypted with
$k$ (the usual 56 bits key size) and $k_1$ (64 bits since the block size)  where $C_2=DESA_{k,k_1}(P_2)$ and $C_3=DESA_{k,k_1}(P_3)$
So one can x-or given two ciphertext and:

$C_2\oplus C_3 = DESA_{k,k_1}(P_2)\oplus DESA_{k,k_1}(P_3)= DES_k(P_2)\oplus k_1\oplus DES_k(P_3)\oplus k_1=DES_k(P_2)\oplus DES_k(P_3)$

So, $k_1$ is gone. In the worst case, one tries $2^{56}$ times and get $k$ with two plaintext-ciphertext pair.

Then, for any ciphertext with the help of previous equation one can calculate the $k_1$

$$C_1 = DES_k(P_1)\oplus k_1$$

knowing the key $k$ one can calculate $k_1$.

So in total $2^{57}+1$ DES encryption is called, instead of $2^{56+64}$ key size.

Comment: Thank you , i will check it.

Comment: You may want to note that DES keys only have 56 and 128 bit effective length and that DES blocks are also only 64-bit.

Comment: thanks and fixed